# JQuery problem in Internet Explorer 8

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer-8

The following code works fine in Firefox, but not in IE. I have tried various tweaks to both header and script call string, however nothing will make IE run the scripts. Also all security is turned off in IE.

*Is there anything wrong in the following code?*

```
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Smartube</title>
    <link href="css/default.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="tubeutil.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="init.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function formfocus() {
    document.getElementById('1').focus();
    }
    window.onload = formfocus;
    </script>
    </head>

    <body>



<div class="wrapper">
    <img class="displayed" src="gfx/sb.png">
    <form class="blocks" action="" method="get">
        <p><input type="text"  class="search" id="1" /></p>
        <p><input type="Submit" class="btn" value="" /></p>
        <ul class="reset autocomplete"></ul>
    </form>

    <ul class="reset videos"></ul>

</div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 6):

Your code isn't really jQuery, it's straight javascript, but your problem here is that the W3C standard requires an ID to begin with a letter (see http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_standard_id.asp).

You could write your script as jQuery like so:

```
function formfocus( ) {
    $('#myid').focus( );
}
$(window).load( formfocus );
```

EDIT: OK, I've just tested the following in IE:

HTML:

```
<div class="wrapper">
 <img class="displayed" src="gfx/sb.png">
    <form class="blocks" action="" method="get">
        <p><input type="text"  class="search" id="my1" value="" /></p>
        <p><input type="Submit" class="btn" value="" /></p>
        <ul class="reset autocomplete"></ul>
    </form>

    <ul class="reset videos"></ul>

</div>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready( function ( ) {
  $('#my1').focus( );
});
```

That works in IE9, so I think it should work in 8 too. Test version is here: http://jsbin.com/ipezey/edit#javascript,html

Also, as per thirtydot's answer, This test version has an HTML 5 doctype, whereas your version has none. This could be the root of your problem.

Comment: +1. To add to that, in jQuery you don't need for the whole window `load` event, you can start manipulating the DOM on document `ready` event. :)

Comment: Very true, I thought I'd write this as a strict jQuery translation of his code, but yes, I would normally just use `$(function( ) {` ...

Answer (score 1):

> Is there anything wrong in the following code?

One thing strikes me as wrong, but there's no way I can know if it's the cause of your problems (I can't see the rest of your JavaScript).

You're missing a valid doctype, so Internet Explorer is in [Quirks Mode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quirks_mode), which is very bad!

Add this as the very first line:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```

Answer (score 0):

as you can read [on this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70579/what-are-valid-values-for-the-id-attribute-in-html)

> ID and NAME tokens must begin with a letter ([A-Za-z]) and may be
>   followed by any number of letters, digits ([0-9]), hyphens ("-"),
>   underscores ("_"), colons (":"), and periods (".").

so "1" is not a valid id. change that id to "id1" or "searchfield" to make the script work in all browsers.

as a sidenote: as others said, you aren't actually using jqery here, but this isn't the problem.

Answer (score 0):

First: `id="1"` [is not a valid ID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70579/what-are-valid-values-for-the-id-attribute-in-html).

Second: Since you're using jQuery, I'd suggest that you use jQuery (!):

```
$(function(){
  $('#that-form-element').focus();
});
```

That will run `$('#that-form-element').focus();` once the page (DOM) is ready.

Answer (score 0):

`id` Specifies a unique id for an element within an HTML Document.

Naming rules:

```
Must begin with a letter A-Z or a-z
Can be followed by: letters (A-Za-z), digits (0-9), hyphens ("-"), underscores ("_"), colons (":"), and periods (".")
Values are case-sensitive
```

Answer (score -1):

You are not using jquery at all.

use this notation :

```
$(function() {
    $('#1').focus();
});
```

instead of all your javascript

Comment: this won't solve the problem, "1" simply isn't a valid id according to the standards.